# Chrome/Firefox - Hide all all except address bar

Tags: .net, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am launching a browser (either Chrome/Firefox) from a c# process running on Windows. From this call I  would like to hide the toolbar, tab, navigation options etc in Chrome/Firefox. However, I would like the address bar to still be visible. So my browser would look something like this:

[image]

Some extra facts:

1. We cant use pop ups.
2. We have played around with with the kiosk mode command line options when launching the browser.exe but these hide the address bar as well. so --app in (chrome) and -chrome in (Firefox) would be perfect if I could still show the address bar, or even show the address bar on the border of the browser (infact if the address was readonly - it would be better).
3. Ideally I would like to do this from the server launch, but if there is another non pop up approach using js, then I am very interested.

Thanks for your help